# What is the Proto-Indo-European root word for electricity?

Tags: etymology

When I looked at Wiktionary for the word electricity, I saw that it came from the Ancient Greek word "elektron", and saw that it was possibly from Sanskrit ulka, which came from what appears to be *rka or something like that. That word appears to mean meteor.

Note: that word coming from meteor means that the word has evolved a lot but still has a scientific meaning.

Comment: Please don't ask for the etymology of arbitrary words here.

Comment: What is the Proto-Semitic root for jet fuel?

Answer (score 10):

There is no PIE root word for electricity because the phenomenon wasn't known and identified at that time. Ancient Greek *ἤλεκτρον* means "amber" and is the name of a gold-silver alloy, the transfer of the word to electricity happened only in Early Modern English.

The wiktionary entry on *ἤλεκτρον* uses a very hedging language with lots of "possibly", "or", and "or". Its etymology is not really well-established. Also, back-checking from Sanskrit  उल्का gets to different, again, "possible" cognates like  Proto-Celtic *lowtus (“ash”) (compare Welsh lludw (“ash”), Breton ludu (“ash”), and "or" and "or" (only Vulcanus is discarded as a potential cognate because of presumed Etruscan origin).

Comment: Fun fact, there are only two kut of dozents of languages in wiktionaries translation that don't borrow "vulcan" are Iceland and Hawaii, if I remember correctly. Anyhow, *vulcan* could be a loan into etruscan why not. cp, *swelt*, G *schwelen* "smolder", also *Rauch-Wolke* "smoke cloud"; or \*bhlew-. Words for "mount" abound in all forms, pick one, say *Kur-gan*; and for the god, *khan* or other king words. Vice Versa, pre-greek borrowing from Etruscan is not unfathomable either.

Comment: Something seems to have gone wrong in the last sentence -- *and "or" and "or"*?

Comment: Maybe my English is not perfect here. I want to come back to the theme of the first sentence of the second paragraph: Several hypotheses are presented in a very hedging language.

Answer (score 4):

The English word "electricity" can trace its ancestry back to Greek *ἤλεκτρον* (*ělektron*), meaning "amber" (because rubbing amber against cloth can give it an electric charge). But where exactly this word comes from is disputed.

Some sources link it with Sanskrit *ulkā* "meteor", but that word's etymology is *also* disputed, so it doesn't help much. I've seen *ulkā* linked to Latin *Vulcānus* ("Vulcan") before, but that seems unlikely, since Etruscan inscriptions refer to a god *Velchan* and the ending *-an* appears in various Etruscan nouns.

Others link it with Ancient Greek *ἥλιος* (*hělios*), "sun", or the obscure *ἠλέκτωρ* (*ēléktōr*) "the beaming sun" found in Homer. This seems more plausible to me. In the former case, the PIE root is **sóh₂wl*, "sun", cognate with Latin *sōl* and English *sun*; in the latter case, it's unknown and might be pre-Greek.

Comment: I've chosen to link *elector* with *select*, *elect*, "sē- (“without; apart”) + legō (“gather, select”)", because a large share of electronics is choosing the right parts to minimize cost, lol. It's pretty close to *lewk- (“white; light; bright"), perhaps notable. Ger *Bern-Stein* "amber" reminds a little of \bhe-w- > *beam*; we talk of *static* electricity after all; it's said instead to relate to *burn* < \*bhrewh1-, akin to *brimstone*. En *amber* is traced to middle Persian *'mbr*, via Arabic *anbar* (al anbar?); ...

Comment: @vectory Choosing electronic parts to minimize cost happened well after Homer's time, and thus could not have influenced his word choice.

Comment: Is ἠλέκτωρ related to ἥλιος? The dictionaries don't seem to think so, and it's hard to see how it could be derived.

Comment: @TKR Wiktionary thinks so, though that's not a great source. LSJ annoyingly doesn't say one way or another (and that's my usual source for AGrk stuff).

Comment: LSJ is unreliable on etymology. Chantraine and Beekes are better places to look, and neither connects the two words.

Comment: @TKR Interesting! I don't have access to either right now but I'll take your word for it and update the answer.

Comment: ... *amber* replaced OE *eolhsand* "elksand" (cognate?); the same page has an OE entry *amber* "bucket", uncertain, either akin to or directly from *amphora* or, I don't see how, from PGem \*ainaz "one" ... cp the Leiden Jar, but note that no ancient batteries have been found confirmed. Anyhow, *-tron* was a frequent agent suffix.

Comment: I'd compare Bernstein to *brown*, because of the color (if brown used to cover that); We still talk of *Braun-Kohle* which burns quite well, and graphit is a conductor if I'm not mistaken (e.g. the brush in servo motors). Then cp \*ghel- "yellow" (also green), probably meaning "light, radiant" in a two color system opposed to red or earthy, dull colors, I believe, that was extended as needed. Most color words reconstruct "shiny" anyway, lol

Comment: swing and a miss: \*ǵʰelh₃- derives AGr *Kh-* (unless it went through Italic > *H*, which might be anachronistic for all I know). Rather cp Lat *silex* "flintstone", likewise of unknown origin, which would confirm the *s-*.

Comment: Can ἠλέκτωρ be cognate with light, that is "light emitter"? Maybe a borrowing from another IE language?

Comment: @Anixx What language would it be a borrowing from? It's entirely possible, but Pre-Greek seems like an easier assumption. (If it's from *l-wk, where's the ē come from?)

Comment: @Draconis cannot ē compensate for loss of w?

Comment: @Anixx I'd be very surprised to see *lewk- become ēlek-; that would be a pretty big metathesis.

Comment: @Draconis The initial ē- is probably from the prefix eghs-, so the PIE form is eghsleukter. Compare Russian izlučatel - light source. Compare also Latin elector where the e- prefix came from eghs-.